# mysql- pivot rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a database where I have the following contact table in the image:

| idservicio | idcliente | nombre contacto | telefono |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76543 | 2 | maria perez | 123456 |
| 76543 | 2 | miguel o | 765433 |
| 98765 | 1 | sara perez | 876658 |
| 98765 | 1 | jose o | 987665 |
| 98765 | 1 | orlando | 876540 |
| 76543 | 3 | jack | 123456 |
| 76543 | 3 | ana | 654324 |
| 76543 | 3 | kevin | 954326 |

and I want to perform a query where the output is as follows:

| idservicio | idcliente | telefono 1 | telefono 2 | telefono 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76543 | 2 | 123456 | 765433 |  |
| 98765 | 1 | 876658 | 987665 | 876540 |
| 76543 | 3 | 123456 | 654324 | 954326 |

In sql server I did it with row_number over partition by , how can I do it in mysql,  I have version 5.7.36

Comment: MySQL do have row_number(). https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) This also applies to database schemas, sample data and desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
I included the tables as text

Comment: @cudris In fact, MySQL 8+ supports `ROW_NUMBER`.  So your current SQL Server query should also run on newer versions of MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I have mysql version 5.7.36

Comment: You can generate pseudo-column with something like this ```select sum(1) over (order by nombre_contacto,telefono),t.*  from test_tab t;```